# How is bias term calculated in SVMs?

Tags: machine-learning, svm

I am reading John C. Platt's paper on the SMO algorithm for training SVMs. In this paper(in section 2.3) the bias is computed using the formulas (20) and (21).

Can you provide a detailed explanation and derivation of these formulas used to calculate the bias term?

Also, how is bias usually calculated in SVMs after you solve the dual problem using some other algorithm instead of SMO (basically I'm asking for a connection between the bias term and the optimal Lagrange Multipliers)?

Link to Platt's paper: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8b5e/ab2c9fefe2fb1cc15e755cf7382ffc638f7c.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally speaking the bias term is calculated based on the support vectors that lie on the margins (i.e., having $0 < \alpha_i < C$). This is because for these vectors we have $y_i(w^Tx_i +b) = 1$. Noting that $y_i^2=1$, we get $b=y_i - w^Tx_i$ for any such vector. From a numerical stability standpoint, and in particular when taking into account the stopping criteria, the actual value may not be $1$, so generally one averages over the values when performing the calculation.