# how to calculate b in SVM if we have the optimum solution

Tags: machine-learning, svm

In a SVM classifier.
$$\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{w},b}\quad &\frac{\|\mathbf{w}\|}{2}+ C \sum_{i=1}^{N} \xi^{(i)}, \\
s.t.\quad&y^{(i)} (\mathbf{w^T}\mathbf{x}^{(i)}+b) \ge 1 - \xi^{(i)},&\forall i \in \{1,\dots,N\} \\
\quad&\xi^{(i)}\ge0, &\forall i \in \{1,\dots,N\} 
\end{align}$$
if we have optimal $w$ and $\xi^{(i)}$ can we compute $b$? My guess is using train samples in $O(N)$ complexity we can compute it, but I can't prove it.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91269/deriving-the-optimal-value-for-the-intercept-term-in-svm/91544#91544

Comment: As well: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362046/how-is-bias-term-calculated-in-svms/362448#362448

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any support vector $\textbf{x}^{(i)}$, the following holds:
$$
\textbf{w}^T \cdot \textbf{x}^{(i)} + b = y^{(i)}.
$$
This is basically the definition of "*support vector*": It lies on the margin, either on the positive side (+1) for vectors from the positive class, or on the negative side (-1) for the negative class.

So, the simplest way to compute $b$ is simply to take an arbitrary support vector and calculate:
$$
b = y^{(i)} - \textbf{w}^T \cdot \textbf{x}^{(i)},
$$
which, depending on your optimisation algorithm used for finding $\textbf{w}$, can be done even in $O(1)$: In the optimisation phase, you just need to store a support vector as soon as you encounter one, and retrieve it directly when calculating $b$.

In practice, however, for numerical stability, it is preferred to average over all support vectors:
$$
b = \frac{1}{|SV|}\sum_{i \in SV}y^{(i)} - \textbf{w}^T \cdot \textbf{x}^{(i)},
$$
where $SV$ is the set of support vectors. Here, the complexity is obviously at least $O(|SV|)$, but, unless your optimiser stores all support vectors separately, e.g. in a hash table, you'll probably need to go through the whole set, identifying the support vectors, which would cost you $O(N)$.

Reputable source: Bishop, *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning*, p. 330, eq. (7.18) (using the kernel trick and a slightly different notation).